# I is ideal,if $\left[r\right]=r+I$, why $\left[a\right]+\left[b\right]=\left[a+b\right]$ & $\left[a\right]\cdot \left[b\right]=\left[a\cdot b\right]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I can't find a way to prove it for myself and it seems kind of counter intuitive

I can think of why $\left[a\right]+\left[b\right]=\left[a+b\right]$ would be true (because of $2I\:=\:I$ maybe) but what about $\left[a\right]\cdot \left[b\right]=\left[a\cdot b\right]$?

Comment: For clarification, you should state if you indeed deal with two-sided ideals here.

Comment: Two-sided ideal

Comment: Ok. So that confirms my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

If $i,j \in I$

$$(a+i)(b+j)= ab +aj+ib+ij$$ which belongs to $[a][b]$ if $I$ is a two-sided ideal by definition of a (two-sided) ideal as $aj, ib,ij \in I$.

Same for the sum.

Comment: aj and ib would be an element of I, so if we'd about to write it as a set we'd get ab + I + I, right? But we also get ij which is I*I, and I'm sure that I*I is not equal to I

Comment: For an element of an ideal, this element multiplied by any other element belongs to the ideal... in particular, this is true if both elements belong to the ideal! As an advice, don’t try to manipulate sets when you start with a new notion. Ideals here. Use elements of those sets (ideals here) first to understand in details what happens. Later on you’ll manipulate more abstract notions.